# How to find an item in my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So i want to create a person and add it to my table if i dont have the same name already in my table. i have this code in my controller

```
hesaplamaEntities hsb = new hesaplamaEntities();
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyTable p)
    {

        MyTable obj = hsb.MyTable.Find(p);

        if (obj.propname == null)
        {
            hsb.MyTable.Add(p);
            hsb.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Create", "Home");

        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

and this is my View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = 
"form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{


<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.propname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">kod</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.propkod, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

and this is my Model :

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string propkod { get; set; }
    public string propname { get; set; }

}
```

i am having this error when i am trying to add person :
he specified parameter type 'WebApplication7.Models.MyTable' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.

and its showing me the error in this line : HesapTemel obj = hsb.HesapTemels.Find(p);

what is the probleme exactly ?

Comment: `HesapTemel obj = hsb.HesapTemels.Find(p.Id)`

Comment: You need to show your model. It needs to be `.Find(p.xx)` where `xx` is the PK property of your model

Comment: @DavidG ok i want to look if there is any person with the same name in my table ..it may have another id but the same name

Comment: Then use a `.Where()` clause, not `.Find()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to find the person with the same name.. is there any way to do it .. however i tried **.find(p.Id) ** its not working again.

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: `hsb.HesapTemel.Where(x => x.propname == p.propname)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke again its not working , i have this error now : 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel>' to 'WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Use `.FirstOrDefault()` if you want a single object (although that would be unnecessary - you can just use `.Any()` in your case

Comment: @StephenMuecke  itried all those befor and not working again i have the error : 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: I suggest you spend some time studying the basics of linq.

Comment: @StephenMuecke its not my first time with linq man but its first time i have this error , anyway thankyou i will try to read more about it

Comment: `bool hasDuplicate = hsb.HesapTemal.Any(x => x.propname == p.propname);` And read the first sentence of my first comment.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i added my model ,sorry i forgot it

Comment: the answer was hsb.HesapTemel.Where(x => x.propname == p.propname).ToList(); ... thanks again